# Tried Everything but wp-admin still showing blank screen

Tags: wordpress

I done almost everything, Here is what I have done

- Reinstall Wordpress
- Increase memory size (tried upto 2000 MB)
- Deactivate Plugin
- Deactivate Theme
- Debug set to true
- php starting and end tag
- install php.ini file
- Change php version

But none of them works, The domain.com/wp-admin still showing blank screen. What else should be the possible solution?

Comment: Did you find anything in debug logs?

Comment: Did not found anything

Comment: Did you check the folder and file permissions..

Comment: Yes tried. wp-admin and wp-content has 705 permission. I have also check it with 755

Comment: 1 Is it possible to see your site? Is it online? 2. What happens if you access the main site (without wp-admin), like domain.com, does it open? 3. Was wp-admin working earlier anytime or is it a new installation?

Answer (score 1):

Did you clear your cache and do a hard reload? If you have done that and still it's not showing up, do you access your dashboard with a https link or http link?

Comment: Hard reset doesn't work, Here is the error when accessing through https "This site can’t provide a secure connection
www.domain.com sent an invalid response."